# Why is my Music Bot Lagging? (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js, voice

I have a discord bot with multiple stuff but the music is very laggy. Does anyone know why? (I'm using v12-master)
Code:

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord')

const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();

const dispatcher = await connection.play(await ytdl(url), { type: 'opus' });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things if you are using Heroku as your host it will lag for sure 
or Thats your Bandwidth issue Upgrade your internet plan or use Amazon web server or any other hosting services with better bandwidth

Comment: ahhh that's why my music bot is lagging because I am hosting at Heroku. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: use lavalink and host it on aws or other good services which provides atleast 1 gb ram and good network bandwidth i did the same i hosted my bot in heroku and hosted lavalink in aws ec2 server XD (the free one since its private bot)